# Base and Extension package org

Tags: isv

I have a dev org which acts as Base (main) org. Now one of my client wants some changes while other clients don't want these changes. Now I am planning to have a separate org which will act as Extension org. First I will install Base org's managed package into Extension org and then I will make changes asked by clients in Extension org. After doing that I will upload managed package from Extension org and install it in client's org. This works fine. But my question is Do I need to ISV for this? Do I need to pass security review for both the orgs?

Comment: You need to be an ISV and pass security review only if you want to offer your apps on the AppExchange.

Comment: DO i have to pass security review for both packages?

Comment: As I understand it, you only need to pass Security Review if you plan to publish the app on the app exchange (rather than just have the link available privately to customers). So the base package probably will need to pass review, but the extension will most likely not need to pass review, though customers may require you to before they are willing to install it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From my understanding **YOU WILL ONLY BE REQUIRED** to undergo a security review if you plan to upload the managed packages on the AppExchange.

From your question I don't think this is the case. However, this should not be used as reason to cut corners in terms of best practices.

See this link for more information about the http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Security_Review

Answer (score 0):

To install a managed package, whether or not you list the app publicly, you need to go through the sec review. And both the base package and extension will need to go through the sec review. This is a newer process for SFDC.

Comment: Hi Rich thanks for sharing, can you elaborate please ? or share a link to the new process